# How to get recommendations for a new user using a tensor flow recommenders model

Tags: tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I am using the [following Tensor flow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_ranking) from Google on building a collaborative filter based recommendation model.

The tutorial does not cover how to get predictions for a new user who is not in the original dataset the model was trained on.

E.g A model is trained on the movie lens dataset.  A new user gives ratings on 10 movies from the dataset.   I want to get predictions on the top 10 movies for this user based on the already trained model (without training a new model).

how do I do this?

I don't see any clearly documented procedure on how to do this, the API seems to want to get a user-id/movie ratings dict